# Disable Outline for text-boxes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design, search

Please disable the outline on focus for the search and INTERESTING / IGNORED TAGS fields.

Look these textboxes below:

- [image: Screenshot]                This is from Stack Overflow.
- [image: Screenshot]           This is from [Web Application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).
- and [image: Screenshot] This is from [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Look [this question from Web Application Meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/658/4008) where similar problem is discussed.

Comment: Safari-only? No-repro with other browsers (not even Konqueror).

Comment: I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: I'll disable the outline. Webkit browsers show it by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this. The change will be in the deployment tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. add [status-completed] tag please.